# How to create a new entry based on a condition in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Input XML:

```
.....
..... <!-- Many lines of code -->
.....
<Attribute Name="Attr1">  
  <Array>
       <Object Type="Object1">
          <Attribute Name="Attr2">
              "123"
              "234"
           </Attribute>
           <Attribute Name="Attr3">"456"</Attribute>
        </Object>
        <Object Type="Object2">
           <Attribute Name="Attr4">
               "444"
               "555"
            </Attribute>               
         </Object>
         <Object Type="Object3">
            <Attribute Name="Attr5">
                "666"   
                "777"
                "888"     
    <!-- My new item should come here -->   
             </Attribute>
          </Object> 
   </Array>
</Attribute>
```

I tried the following XSLT to add a new entry(999) to the above mentioned location "My new item should come here". 
Before inserting this new item, I want to check if the node, `Attribute(<Attribute Name = "Attr5")` has a value "888". Only if it contains "888" , I should insert "999" after that. can you please let me knoe how this can be achieved?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
    >
     <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

     <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:variable name="obj" select='"Object3"'/>
     <xsl:variable name="attr" select='"Attr5"'/>
     <xsl:param name="evalue">"999"</xsl:param>

     <xsl:template match="Attribute/Array/Object[@Type=$obj]/Attribute[@Name=$attr]">
      <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:value-of select="$evalue"/>
  </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output XML

```
<Attribute Name="Attr1">  
  <Array>
       <Object Type="Object1">
          <Attribute Name="Attr2">
              "123"
              "234"
           </Attribute>
           <Attribute Name="Attr3">"456"</Attribute>
        </Object>
        <Object Type="Object2">
           <Attribute Name="Attr4">
               "444"
               "555"
            </Attribute>               
         </Object>
         <Object Type="Object3">
            <Attribute Name="Attr5">
                "666"   
                "777"
                "888"     
                "999"
             </Attribute>
          </Object> 
   </Array>
</Attribute>
```

This is how the final XML should look like. Please help me out

Comment: Are you able to use XSLT 2.0, or just XSLT 1.0? Also, can you say exactly what happens when you try it (i.e an error, or unexpected output), as saying "this doesn't work" is a bit vague. Thanks!

Comment: @TimC I am not getting the expected output. I am using XSLT 1.0 and my environment does not provide support to XSLT 2.0

Answer (score 2):

It lacks many instructions in your template...

```
<xsl:template match="Attribute/Array/Object[@Type=$obj]/Attribute[@Name=$attr and contains(., '&quot;888&quot;')]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:value-of select="$evalue"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks this works, I have one more question.. Before inserting this new item, I want to check if the node, Attribute(<Attribute Name = "Attr5") has a value "888". Only if it contains "888" , I should insert "999" after that. can you please let me knoe how this can be achieved?

Comment: I've updated my answer according to your new request.